# What is this web effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When you reach 1000 reputation on stack overflow you get an expendable usercard

[image]

when you mouse hover on the card.

How can I recreate this effect ? How is it called ? My guess is its a Jquery method but if it is can someone point me in the right direction because I looked for it but can't get exactly what I need.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the code and find out?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm a just starting with the web.Even if i look at the source I won't know where to look.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth good like finding something like that...

Comment: there are as many ways to execute this effect as there are web designers in the world. Ok, that may be overstating things, but there are many ways to do this. In general, you attach a `hover` event handler to the element you want to expand. Within the handler, you change the dimensions of the element (perhaps with an animation), and modify the content within it)

Comment: @ianpgall: I haven't looked at the code myself, but I imagine the relevant bits could be isolated pretty quickly by simply removing everything that looks irrelevant.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth looked at the source and posted below. Maybe that's it.. Animate

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ukibaf/2 I'm late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what they use, but [CSS3 transition animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) would be a simple, no programming way to do it.

Comment: Niiice this could do the job !!

Comment: Definitely a very good possibility. But I wouldn't be surprised if it used jQuery, to make sure older browsers that don't support CSS3 can do the same thing.

Comment: @ianpgall, yeah I haven't looked exactly at what SO uses, but although there's this compatibility issue, CSS is usually my first preference. If we don't move the web ahead, it won't, right?

Comment: @AbhranilDas Very true! I would prefer CSS as well, but as soon as you want to do one little thing that that CSS can't (maybe manipulate the DOM or retrieve data from the server) then you mix events between CSS and javascript, and it's harder to handle

Answer (score 3):

A really simple example of what you are after is here http://jsfiddle.net/RjpLt/

It's enough to get you started.

**UPDATE**

Now with ccs animations: http://jsfiddle.net/RjpLt/1/

Comment: It's a nice CSS-only trick, but there are no easing transitions which OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: Added `-moz` and `-o` to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/RjpLt/2/), +1

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell:

When the popup is triggered, a `<div>` with the appropriate content is dynamically added somewhere inside the DOM (most likely Javascript positions the popup as well as creates it). This element starts out small and is then animated to its final dimensions. Meanwhile, CSS rules specify the visual appearance of the popup. When the mouse leaves the popup area, the `<div>` is removed from the DOM, making the popup disappear.

Comment: either that, or the <div> is always there and the hover just shows/animates it and then hides/animates it later

Comment: Simply place a `div` with `position:absolute` positioned at the same `offset().top` and `.left` of the image, start the `div` with `display:none` then call `.show()` with a duration (`.show(500)`) will take care of expanding the div from the top-left to bottom-right when you `mouseover`, and `hide()` it on `mouseleave` (I'd put both functions inside the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)). It would achieve virtually the same effect, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ianpgall: My faultless scientific debugging procedure (show/hide the popup while looking at the dynamic DOM tree in Chrome's dev tools a couple of times) was clear in its conclusion: the div is removed. Doesn't make much of a difference anyway. :)

Comment: @ianpgall Nope, it's `StackExchange.helpers.MagicPopup` function from `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js`. Check, the `div` is created every hover.

Comment: good work. it definitely doesn't matter whether it's added or not, it's just that extra processing that occurs when it is. to me, i'd rather keep it and manipulate it based on being hovered over or not. but it's not my site :)

Comment: I'd rather write the markup in the HTML as well, to keep it more organized. Unless the data needs to be fetched by Ajax, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it does use jQuery, and I'm betting it's "animate":

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The styling animated is probably size and background color, along with other things happening to the area.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'a simple `$('#container).show('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

Since you posed a static image, it is hard to tell what exactly is happening. Here is my guess:

It uses Hover to trigger the events:
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Then Show to show a hidden div:
http://api.jquery.com/show/

Something like:

```
$('a.show-profile').hover(function(){ 
    $('#profile').show();
});
```

The #profile would need to be hidden in advance via css "display: none" or $('#profile').hide();
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Well just mouseover the picture of anyone with over 1000 reputation and you'll see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is  (from the source) :

`StackExchange.helpers.MagicPopup({selector:".user-hover .user-gravatar48, .user-hover .user-gravatar32"`

`$(b).closest(".user-hover").find(".user-details a").attr("href"));return!b?null:"/users/user-info/"+b[1]},cache:!0,id:"user-menu",showing:f,removed:c}))}}}();`

`b.fadeOutAndRemove()):setTimeout(p,500)};b.animate({width:j,height:a,top:f.top+k.top},200,p);`

But as I said i'm new to this so it might not even be related but it's an `Animated onmouseover on the gravatar` .

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 solutions:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ukibaf/4/)*

- Populate dynamically a DIV card with **all** the relevant content.
- Eliminate undesired contents, paragraphs or elements using `display:none` in the CSS
- Only one 'BIG' card will change it's position on the page, cloning and revealing the FULL content on hover - Preparing the CSS for that element to `display:block;` all the contents.

On hover :

- Get the positions of the hovered card
- grab all the 'small'card contents and populate a bigger card one
- Add the hover intent to wait ~180ms before showing the
- Place the BIG card OVER the small one and use `.show(600)` to display it.
- If mouse leaves the BIG card use `.hide()`

jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<div id="userCard"><div id="userCardContent"></div>');

var $hoveredImg;
$('.userCardMini').on('mouseenter','img',function(e){
   $hoveredImg = $(this);
   var thisSrc = $hoveredImg.attr('src').split('s=')[0];
   var posX = $hoveredImg.offset().left-10;
   var posY = $hoveredImg.offset().top-10;
   $('#userCardContent').html( $hoveredImg.parent().html() );
   $('#userCardContent').find('img').attr('src', thisSrc+'s=64&d=identicon&r=PG');
   var t = setTimeout(function() {  
     $('#userCard').css({left:posX, top:posY}).show(600);
   }, 200);     
   $hoveredImg.data('timeout', t);  
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
  clearTimeout($hoveredImg.data('timeout'));
});
$('#userCard').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).stop(1,1).hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="userCardMini" data-user="383904"></div>
<div class="userCardMini" data-user="1063093"></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .badge{
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:11px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2px;
  }
  .gold{background:gold;}
  .silver{background:silver;}
  .bronze{background:#cc9966;}
  
  .userCardMini{
    width:200px;
    height:32px;
    /*background:#eee;*/
    margin:4px;
    clear:both;
  }
  a{color:#27f;}
  img.userImg{
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px -1px #999;
  }
  .userDetails, .userLocation{display:none;}
  /* user card - BIG ONE */
  #userCard{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:280px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px -1px #999;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#666;
    color:#eee;
    display:none;
  }
  #userCardContent{
    width:260px;
    margin:10px;
  }
  #userCardContent a{color:#fff;}
  #userCard .userDetails,
  #userCard .userLocation{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:4px;
  }
```

---

The other solution (I like the most)
 would be to play with DIV elements's CSS and z-index, in the way that - hovering the parent we animate he content (children) element from underneath

### *[jsBin demo 2 - simple solution](http://jsbin.com/iregik/edit#javascript,html,live)*

This bit of jQuery:

```
var $desc;
$('.userCard').hover(function(){  
  
  $desc = $(this).find('.description');
  $(this).css({zIndex:'3'});
   var t = setTimeout(function() {
      $desc.show('slow');
  }, 150);      
  $(this).data('timeout', t);   
  
},function(){
  $(this).css({zIndex:0});
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
  $desc.hide();
  
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="userCard">
    <div class="initial">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/26x26/f7b" /><h2>User name 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <div class="description_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      In et neque quam, vel dapibus neque. Praesent rutrum ultricies sodales.       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .userCard{
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    margin:10px;
  }
  .initial{
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2;
  }
  .userCard img{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px #999;
  }
  .description{
    background:#eee;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding:10px;
    clear:both;
    display:none;
  }
  .description_content{
    padding-top:37px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
  }
```