# Effect on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement a functionality in my web site.I wanted to use the   effect   used in Stack Overflow
when the **mouse is taken over user profile** and the **box is opened showing user profile.** Which effect is used there??
I tried `fade` in and `toggle` but they are not the one..

Comment: google for `tiptip` and `tooltips`.

Comment: it is a dynamic drive tool tip effect you can check at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagetooltip.htm

Comment: Thanks to both of u. I have implemented it in my project. But i am not getting the same effect that is used here

Comment: also when i am using classes of tipTip it shows no class found

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ayafes/1/edit

Comment: @roXon  Thanks a lot mate.  Will try and implement'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267759/what-is-this-web-effect

Comment: @roXon Please don't make edits like that. Vote to close the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @balpha ofcourse, it's just I've voted first to close as "not a real Q" than realizing I already answered one similar ages ago. I just added as suggestion. Thought it should be clear to any moderator. I usually don't ruin good Q :) Thanks